# ValueError: Wrong number of items in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, valueerror

I get the error while running the below functions - ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1.

```
def encoding(df, column_name: str):
  if column_name in df.columns:
    dr = df[column_name].values
    df['Week Day'] = pd.to_datetime(dr).weekday
    df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df[column_name]).month
  df['feature_week_day'] = encoding_1(df,'Week Day',7)
  df['feature_month'] = encoding_1(df,'Month', 12)
  return df

def encoding_1(df, column_name: str, period: int):
  if column_name in df.columns:
    df['sine_' + column_name] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df[column_name] / period)
    df['cosine_' + column_name] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * df[column_name] / period)
  return df
```

I call these functions using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':['ABC123', 'ABC124', 'ABC125', 'ABC126'], 'Date':['2008-01-01','2008-01-02','2020-02-01', '20210419']})
result = encoding(df,'Date')
```

Not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: actually there are 2 errors in your code1st is key error and 2nd is value error

Comment: @AnuragDabas: Sorry, can you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `encoding_1` return an entire dataframe and you are assigning it to a column on the original dataframe. Replace:

```
# ...
df['feature_week_day'] = encoding_1(df,'Week Day',7)
df['feature_month'] = encoding_1(df,'Month', 12)
# ...
```

with:

```
# ...
df = encoding_1(df,'Week Day',7)
df = encoding_1(df,'Month', 12)
# ...
```